# Jenkins declarative when condition to check if a variable is NULL

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to skip Build stage if AMI already exists using declarative syntax.

```
stage('Build') {
  environment {
    AMI = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'aws ec2 describe-images').trim()
  }
  when {
    expression { AMI = null }
  }
  steps {
    sh 'packer build base.json -machine-readable'
  }
}
```

But when I'm running this pipeline I get `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: AMI for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

At the same time scripted pipeline works perfectly fine

```
stage('Build') {
  steps {
    script {
      env.AMI = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'aws ec2 describe-images').trim()
        if (env.AMI == '') {
          sh 'packer build base.json -machine-readable'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd really love to switch to the declarative pipelines just stuck with this condition. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

I tried a lot things without any luck

```
when {
  expression {
    return AMI.isEmpty()
  }
}
```

```
when {
  not {
    expression {
      AMI == ''
  }
}
```

```
when {
  not {
    expression { env.AMI }
  }
}
```

Nothing works. I suspect it is somehow related to env variable association through sh

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
              when {
                expression { 
                    return isAMIAvailable()
                }
              }
            steps {
                sh 'packer build base.json -machine-readable'
            }
        }
    }
}

def isAMIAvailable() {
    AMI = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'aws ec2 describe-images').trim()
    return AMI == null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With @ycr help I was able to build it!
Just in case here is the whole thing

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    ENV = 'dev'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      when { not { expression { return isAMIAvailable() } } }
      steps {
        sh 'packer build base.json -machine-readable'
      }
    }
  }
}

def isAMIAvailable() {
  AMI = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --filters 'Name=name,Values=base-${ENV}-1' --query 'Images[*].[Name]' --output text").trim()
  if (AMI == '') {
    return AMI == null
  }
  return AMI
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).